# xpages application layout bootstrap 3 - error in right column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages-extlib

If I use bootstrap divs in the right column of the appLayout, I get the "funny" effect that in screen size `sm` the right column overlays the center column. 
I think it's a missing definition in the div class of the right column (code automatically generated from the XPages ExtLib):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 applayout-content"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 applayout-column-right">
        <div class="well" style="height:400px;">Right Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I enter a col-sm definition in firebug like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 applayout-content"> ... </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 applayout-column-right">
        <div class="well" style="height:400px;">Right Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works as expected, the effect is gone. Am I missing something, or is it a bug in the ExtLib application layout control?

XPages on 9.0.1 server, ExtLib version is 901v00_16.20160128-1014

Uwe

Comment: What are the contents of your right column? You mentioned on the OpenNTF forum that it required some divs using bootstrap classes? It does look like a bug in the ExtLib code though. A simple fix if I can verify the use case that causes a problem

Comment: Ah got it, if you add `<div class="well"></div>` to the right column, then it overlaps the central column on sm screens/devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is a bug in the application layout control when using the `bootstrapResponsiveApplicationConfiguration`. I have reproduced the issue in an app using `Bootstrap3.theme` and a well in the right column facet. The missing `col-sm` class is indeed the cause, as you suggested.

I have logged the issue on our [github repository for the ExtLib](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/issues/70). A fix will be delivered for this issue in the next release of the Extension Library. Thanks for highlighting/finding it.

**UPDATE**: The fix for this issue is in the latest ExtLib release, ExtLib 17, which was released on the openntf site yesterday (2nd June 2016)

Comment: Thanks Brian for fixing it. 
BTW: Wouldn't it be a cool feature, if the user can configure the definitions of these columns? 
I started to generate a template custom control for layout grids in our applications, where I predefined  (e.g.) 4  <xp:div>s plus a (notes) profile doc in which I can configure the class and the rendering of these <xp:div>s. If you are interested, I will mail it to you (or post it here somewhere).

Comment: Could be a useful feature for the app layout control. Maybe something to look at in the future.

Comment: FYI, the fix for this issue is in the latest ExtLib release, ExtLib 17, which was released on the openntf site yesterday (2nd June 2016)

Answer (score 0):

Is the "col-md-10 col-sm-9 applayout-content" supposed to be closed so that the two appear side by side?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 applayout-content">
        Some text here...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 applayout-column-right">
        More text here...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When on an xs screen, then the divs are shown vertically under each other (which is fine), but on a sm screen, the right column overlays the center one and makes that invisible.

The center column (col-md-10 col-sm-9 applayout-content) should never be closed, it has to be visible on every screen.